# How to test NodeJs CLI javascript

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I need to put some tests around a nodejs command line utilities\modules. No browser involved and I'm using a lot of the "fs" module to work the file system, so i'm not sure a browser based test mechanism would work (sandboxing).

any modules that would help here?

Comment: It is not clear at all what your requirements are or what exactly you are trying to do.  This question as it stands appears to be asking for a third party resource and is far too broad and unclear - all three of which are reasons for it to be considered off-topic for the forum and closed.

Comment: Usually, a command line program creates some output and you test that output to see if it is the desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Vorpal.js](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal). This lets you create an interactive CLI in node, in which you can then run custom commands to test the various things you want to test.

*Disclaimer: I am its author.*

Comment: Great. Looks like just what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it can help! Feel free to post any Vorpal questions on SO.